# Is there a need or how to write a test on main.pl which is not module and run it using Perl Devel cover

Tags: perl, devel-cover

There are lots of material talking about writing coverage on module but how if I want to write a test for command runnable perl script (main.pl)?

Is there a need to write test for main.pl or I just need to write test for module will do?

Let's say I have these two scripts.

command runnable script

## main.pl

```
import Halo;
&main;
sub main() {
    my $a = 2;
    my $b = 3;
    my $c = Halo.add($a, $b);
    print "a + b = $c\n";
}
```

==============================================

Perl module

## Halo.pm

```
package Halo;
sub add() {
    my ($class, $a, $b) = @_;
    return $a + $b;
}
1;
```

==============================================

Run in command line:
perl main.pl

Comment: [Here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/263960/33560) is an example of testing a script written as a modulino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you research "unit" and "end-to-end" testing to understand the benefits of each.  I would recommend that you do both.  Testing your main script is easily done with "modulinos", allowing you to fairly painlessly tie into the existing Perl testing ecosystem.

Answer (score 1):

From the synopsis: https://metacpan.org/pod/Devel::Cover#SYNOPSIS

```
$ perl -I. -MDevel::Cover main.pl
$ cover
```

You'll also need to change your code a bit.  You'll need "use" instead of "import" and "Halo->add" instead of "Halo.add".  (These changes are nothing to do with Devel::Cover.)